# Gradle creates modules from caches in IntellijIdea

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

[image: Modules]

Hello,

I have a problem using IntellijIdea + Gradle 4.4.

With every gradle build, Intellij Idea creates a new module group adding the dependencies from gradle caches. It's useless to remove the module.

Here is my gradle configuration.

[image: Configuration]

Thanks!!

Comment: There is a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187917

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect that. Thanks, I think I will wait for the fix. 
I will leave this question open cause I think it might be useful for other people.