# IntelliJ Module structure after Gradle import

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I a (common) Gradle multi-project build I have a root with four sub-projects. Each with their own build.gradle and a common build.gradle, settings.gradle and gradle.properties in the root folder.

It all builds an works as expected - except for one thing I can't figure out:

When importing the gradle-build into IntelliJ (import from external model) IntelliJ creates two separate modules at root-level. One is marked as a normal Module and one as a Grouped module. It is the latter that surprises me - why is this created? It makes no sense to have in as a module in IntelliJ since it only points to some downloaded jar-files in my .gradle folder. See below picture.

I've create several gradle multi-project builds and worked with IntelliJ for several years - yet I have never seen this nor do I know how to get rid of it..

[image]

Comment: Try 2019.1 RC from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion The related issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187917) has been fixed there. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036569 as a duplicate.

Comment: Great - thanks. Wonder why that post was so hard to find.... :)

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading to 2019.1 RC fixes the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000323/andrey) said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300018/intellij-module-structure-after-gradle-import/55353072#comment97351446_55300018):

> Try 2019.1 RC from jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion The related issue ([youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187917](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187917)) has been fixed there. See also [stackoverflow.com/questions/54036569](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54036569) as a duplicate.

Which fixes the issue.